# How to put multiple conditions together in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I am trying to extract the count of certain values. I have written one condition where it finds the substring and matches the elements, I wanna add one more condition such that it takes count only if the Grade(one more column with grade values like A, B, C) is "A". How can I put it together?

```
sub= 'GAV'  
x = [s for s in df.ModuleCode if sub in s ]
len(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple conditions into a statement like

```
len( df[ (df.ModuleCode.str.contains(sub)) & (df.Grade=='A') ]  )
```

You can keep that info around as a new column, if you want, e.g. by

```
df['met_conditions'] = (df.ModuleCode.str.contains(sub)) & (df.Grade=='A')
```

Comment: Also, if I had to print count for each grade, how can I improvise the same code?

Comment: first off you are invited to mark that answer as correct if it sufficed...